# log4net error when integrating with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, log4net

When I add the log4net section to the app.config file, I get the following error:

{"An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Unable to Initiate GlobalChangeReason load due to db error: The type initializer for 'prjProcessWorkSheets.AicDatabase' threw an exception."}

The log4net section that I am adding is:

```
  <log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
        <levelMin value="INFO" />
      </filter>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>


    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="C:\Test\Test.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline%exception%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>

    <logger name="ProcessingApp">
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="SmtpAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>

  </log4net>
```

Added to AssemblyInfo.vb

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XMLConfigurator(ConfigFile:="log4net", Watch:=True)>
```

Error Stack Trace:

prjProcessWorkSheets.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create_*Instance*_[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
   at prjProcessWorkSheets.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_frmSteps()
   at prjProcessWorkSheets.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\Users\mattoou\Desktop\VSS-REPO\Processing Application\prjProcessWorkSheets\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at prjProcessWorkSheets.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with log4net?  The exception is indicating is coming from `prjProcessWorkSheets.AicDatabase` which I assume is part of your code.

Comment: the moment I comment out the log4net section of the app.config - the error goes away. I know it is strange

Comment: Well what code in the `prjProcessWorkSheets.AicDatabase` type initializer is throwing the error?

Comment: added the stack trace...

Comment: That stack trace means nothing to us since we don't have your code.  You'll have to post the relevant code, but really you know what line is throwing the exception - use a debugger and figure out why it is throwing.

Comment: @Code12: That stack trace seems to point to the type initialization.  But you need to dig into the exception more.  What you're seeing is an exception telling you that another exception was thrown.  That other exception (which is *probably* an inner exception) is what you need to find.

Answer (score 0):

How are you *using* Log4Net in the code?  This part of the error speaks volumes:

> The type initializer for 'prjProcessWorkSheets.AicDatabase' threw an exception.

The class `prjProcessWorkSheets.AicDatabase` seems to be trying to *do something* when it initializes.  A static constructor?  Inline-initialized members?  If the pattern has to do with the log4net config, then I'm guessing *one* of the things it's trying to do is initialize a logger.

*That* is the exception you're looking for.  Is it an inner exception of the one you're receiving?  If not, either stop on it in a debugger or initialize the class within a method where you can catch the exception.  It should tell you what's wrong with log4net.

Comment: @Code12: What does the inner exception say?  If the pattern holds, then it's probably an exception when trying to initialize a log4net logger.  Move that initialization into a method where you can catch the exception.  Then you can see the actual error that started this.